# Xbox one update problem

Tags: xbox-one

I have just started playing xbox one whenever i insert a game it demands an update thats too big. I dont want to play online at the moment, I just want to play offline. I want suggestions.

Comment: What game is it?

Comment: @TimmyJim - I think the OP means any game - i.e. no matter which game it is, it forces you to download an update.  On the 360 you could cancel the update and play offline.  I presume the OP wants to know if/how to do this on Xbox One games.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to disconnect your Xbox One from the internet. There are 2 ways to do it.

- Physically unplug the LAN cable and disconnect from your WiFi network.
- "[**Go offline**](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/networking/network-settings)". Go to the "Network settings" and select "Go offline".